# How to run automation scripts on remote Appium server using public IP?

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop

I have deployed automation script in remote ubuntu-server and i want to execute those script on my local system where appium server is running.I have googled for the answer but all the solutions work only if both the device are connected to same wifi network

Please suggest me the solution to run the script in my local system where Appium server  exist.

Answer (score 0):

1. Where is the device - is It connected at ubuntu-Server?
2. Where is appium server running?
3. Where are the test scripts?

I have tried in this way and it worked.

1. Test scripts are available in System-1
2. Appium Server & Devices are available in another system. Where devices are connected through a physical cable.

With this approach, I am able to run the scripts remotely from my machine. 
Observations: We can try out through accessing devices through WIFI (adb wifi google it). But if wifi fluctuates then appium session will be terminated. To avoid all these go with the physical usb connection.

Comment: Hi..as i mentioned in my previous comment scripts are running in remote ubuntu server and appium server and device connected in local system...your approach will work if both the system are connected to same network/wifi but what if both the system connected to  two different network??